# Does Android Beacon Library with Bluetooth 3.0 device detect BLE beacons?

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I am thinking about developing an Android app using Android Beacon Libary which could run using either Bluetooth 3.0 or 4.0 BLE, but would be able to see BLE beacons. The reason is there are still a lot of mobile devices supporting BT 3.0 out there, but not a lot supporting BT 4.0.
The Android Beacon Libary failed when detecting BT 3.0 as it expects BT LE device. Is there a work around for it ?

Answer (score 2):

The Android Beacon Library is based on Bluetooth Low Energy beacon detection which requires Bluetooth 4.0.  Classic Bluetooth, supported by Bluetooth 3.0, uses incompatible SDKs and is not supported by this library.  Bluetooth beacon technology is almost exclusively based on Bluetooth Low Energy because mobile devices have limited battery capacity and it is not practical to scan for classic Bluetooth devices regularly without draining batteries.